# Rust non-exhaustive match with u32 and usize

Tags: rust

I was trying to write an exhaustive match statement over a (u32, usize) tuple in rust, here is a minimal example:

```rust
fn test(x: u32, y: usize) {
    match (x, y) {
        (0, 0) => todo!(),
        (0, 1..) => todo!(),
        (1.., 0) => todo!(),
        (1.., 1..) => todo!(),
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that this is non-exhaustive and is missing this case:

```rust
(0_u32, _) | (1_u32..=u32::MAX, _) => todo!()
```

Strangely this works with (u32, u32) tuples, but not a heterogeneous (u32, usize) tuple. Is this a compiler problem, or am I really missing an edge case?

Comment: This simpler [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=43932487da985a8d7d106a55b0e8abc6) show the same missing case but with additional details: _`usize` does not have a fixed maximum value, so a wildcard `_` is necessary to match exhaustively_, but I don't know why...

Comment: You could avoid the `1..` part as what else is it going to be if not `0`? Just go with `_`.

Comment: @rodrigo Your link is to the homepage of the playground.

Comment: @tadman That is what I ended up doing, but I was curious why this would fail.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking questions, of course.

Answer (score 3):

This *should* work, and work on that is tracked on [tracking issue #56354: precise pattern matching on pointer size types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56354). The problem is that matching on `usize` and `isize` is not similar to matching on other integers, in that if you match `0..=usize::MAX` you still haven't covered the whole `usize` range because there are different platforms. But half-open patterns should indeed be allowed.